A talking typewriter?
A movie about a writer who goes on some kind of strange journey with a talking typewriter. In one scene there are people drinking from straws in people's heads, and dealers make an addictive drug from giant centipedes. 
The movie came out in the 80's or 90's.
The movie is on the tip of my tongue but I just can't remember what it's called.

Naked Lunch by William S Burroughs, starring Peter Weller. A Cronenberg film. See the synopsis on imdb.com here.From the plot summary:Exterminator Bill Lee finds himself following his wife into an addiction to the bug powder he uses. After accidentally killing her, he descends into a hallucinatory existence in which he imagines himself a secret agent answering to a series of bizarre creatures. He channels his energies into writing "reports" on his delusional mission, while trying to break his addiction. The story loosely reflects events in the life of author Burroughs as he wrote the novel.
